# Driver failed programming external connectivity: ... bind: cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

In my development environment I want to simulate a "web farm" deployment, where I have several "physical" nodes running multiple services, which belong to the same network.

So, say I have 5 nodes, each node will host 1 `mysql`, 1 `nginx` and 2 `web` apps. And `mysql` will bind to the same port `3306`, but on different ip addresses.

I started to write down `docker-compose` config and stuck on a very first step: Docker refuses to create new ip in a given network and bind mysql to a port on that ip.

That's the configuration I'm trying to use:

```
version: "3"

services:
    node1_sql:
        image: mariadb:10.0.33
        restart: always
        networks:
          skkb:
            ipv4_address: 10.9.2.2
        ports: 
         - 10.9.2.2:3306:3306
        environment:
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
        volumes:
         - ./sql_data/1:/var/lib/mysql
        command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci

networks:
    skkb:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 10.9.2.0/24
```

When I try to do `docker-compose up` I get following error:

```
Creating network "node-r_skkb" with driver "bridge"
Creating node-r_node1_sql_1 ... error

ERROR: for node-r_node1_sql_1  Cannot start service node1_sql: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint node-r_node1_sql_1 (24a8412b80ebc95f5b15f5d4ea5281639d6914f312f525cf8803ed5179b906a7): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 10.9.2.2:3306: bind: cannot assign requested address

ERROR: for node1_sql  Cannot start service node1_sql: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint node-r_node1_sql_1 (24a8412b80ebc95f5b15f5d4ea5281639d6914f312f525cf8803ed5179b906a7): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 10.9.2.2:3306: bind: cannot assign requested address
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

If I try to bind to `10.9.2.1`, it works no problem. So it seems to me that it cannot create new IP address which is configured as `ipv4_address: 10.9.2.2`

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Do the artificial IP addresses need to be visible outside Docker space?

Comment: @DavidMaze, sort of. I want to be able to connect to port 80 from my host to any of the deployed containers.